# Как сделать биндинг кнопки которая внутри элемента ListView WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

У меня есть ListView, который выводит содержимое, всего 4 столбца: номер главы, заголовок, кнопка редактирования, кнопка удаления. При нажатии на кнопку мне нужно получить элемент, где она находится (например, номер главы или название главы). Я попытался сделать привязку через имя ListView и через FindAncestor, но ничего не получилось. Пожалуйста, помогите решить эту проблему или укажите на ошибки.

XAML:

```
<ListView Name="TableOfContents" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ContentList}" 
                              Background="{x:Null}" Width="600"
                              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"                              
                              BorderBrush="{x:Null}">

                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                                    Command="{Binding Command}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TableOfContents, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Width="50">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ThemeID}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                       Foreground="Black" FontSize="30"
                                                       TextAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn Width="460">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ThemeName}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                       Foreground="Black" FontSize="20"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn Width="40">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Button Content="" ToolTip="Редактировать"
                                                       Foreground="Black" FontSize="18"
                                                    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                                                      AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}},
                                                                      Path=TableOfContentsPageViewModel.EditTheme}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn Width="40">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Button Content="❌" ToolTip="Удалить"
                                                    Foreground="Black" FontSize="18"
                                                    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                                                      AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}},
                                                                      Path=TableOfContentsPageViewModel.DeleteTheme}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>


                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
```

ViewModel:

```
class TableOfContentsPageViewModel:BaseViewModel, IPageViewModel
    {
        public string SearchedChapter { get; set; }
        public Visibility CanEdit { get; set; } = Visibility.Hidden;
        public Theme SelectedTheme { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Theme> ContentList { get; set; }

        public TableOfContentsPageViewModel()
        {
            ContentList = new ObservableCollection<Theme>(TrainSQL_Commands.GetAllThemes());
            CanEdit = CurrentUser.Role == "Administrator" ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        private ICommand _editTheme;
        public ICommand EditTheme
        {
            get
            {
                return _editTheme ?? (_editTheme = new RelayCommand(x =>
                  {
                      MessageBox.Show("Edit theory");
                  }));
            }
        }

        private ICommand _deleteTheory;
        public ICommand DeleteTheme
        {
            get
            {
                return _deleteTheory ?? (_deleteTheory = new RelayCommand(x =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Delete theory");
                }));
            }
        }
    }
```

Картинка: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wooBo.png

Comment: Зачем вы используете расширение `Interaction.Triggers` там, где можно просто обойтись стандартыми `InputBindings`? При этом вы передаете в команду контрол, что напрочь ломает шаблон MVVM. Вообще `InteractionTriggers` - это костыль для тех, кто не смог до конца слезть с Winforms и изучить все возможности WPF. Да, я согласен, бывают случаи, когда обработчики событий нужны, но это настолько редкость в очень специфических случаях, что в моих двух больших проектах пригодилась только один раз, и точно не для вызова команд, а для изменения поведения контрола.

Comment: Окей, `SelectedItem` это не контрол, но все равно весьма странный подход. Кстати, у ваших колонок фиксировання ширина, то есть, верстка `ListView` прибита гвоздями к пикселям. Вместо `GridView` предлагаю просто сделать `ItemTemplate`, в него засунуть `DockPanel` с нужными элементами, и получится то же самое, только с эластичной версткой и в 2 раза меньше кода в разметке.

Comment: @aepot, прислушаюсь к вашим рекомендациям, спасибо
Можете подсказать, как получить элемент ListView при нажатии на кнопку, которая в нём расположена?

Comment: Сейчас попробую написать пример.

Comment: Тут еще есть пару нарушений MVVM: 1. `MessageBox` - их не стоит использовать в VM слое просто так. 2. `public Visibility CanEdit { get; set; }` - всем цветам, обводкам, шрифтам и др. место в View слое, Visibility не исключение. Сделайте в VM bool свойство, а в View слое меняйте через триггер, либо сделайте конвертер bool to visibility. По поводу проблемы, смотрите что вам выдает студия при отладке, она должна выдать "не удалось найти то-то в таком-то объекте" и вы думаю сразу поймете, почему не удалось решить через `FindAncestor`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, MessageBox'ы нужны для проверки выполнения нажатия(по итогу их не будет), а CanEdit должен скрывать/показывать кнопки удаления и редактирования в зависимости от роли пользователя

Comment: @YAVAY Отвыкайте использовать `MessageBox`, используйте лучше вывод в консоль, а лучше `Debug.WriteLine()`. `CanEdit` - я понимаю, что она должна делать, но только у вас как я и говорил выше должно быть не `CanEdit = Visibility.Visible`, а `CanEdit = true`, а уже XAML разбирает `bool` значение и задает нужные стили. Помните, что в MVVM 3 слоя и каждый слой имеет свои обязанности. Model - обращение с удаленными объектами (база, сайт, документ) и получение от них данных. View - то, что видит пользователь (все стили, цвета). ViewModel - слой, который связывает M и V, реализуя команды например.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Если CanEdit изменить на bool, то кнопка останется видна

Comment: @YAVAY Вы меня не хотите слышать. Прочитайте еще раз мой первый комментарий. Цитата: `Сделайте в VM bool свойство, а в View слое меняйте через триггер, либо сделайте конвертер bool to visibility.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Написал пример. Так как вы знакомы с MVVM, объяснять, что делает каждый класс не буду, но добавлю несколько комментариев в код.

Я не использовал MvvmLight или другие пакеты, чтобы решить задачу, поэтому в код добавил 2 вспомогательных класса, которые были использованы. Один для `INotifyPropertyChanged`, второй для `ICommand`.

```csharp
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);
}

public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private TableOfContentsViewModel _contentList;
    private bool _isAdmin;

    public TableOfContentsViewModel ContentList // здесь хранится ToC
    {
        get => _contentList;
        set
        {
            _contentList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool IsAdmin // права админа
    {
        get => _isAdmin;
        set
        {
            _isAdmin = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // пример асинхронной загрузки
    private async Task LoadTableOfContentsAsync()
    {
        // ...
        await sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        // ...
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        IsAdmin = true; // сделать админом

        // загрузка ToC должна производиться из класса, отвечающего за работу с данными
        // из конструктора это делать не рекомендуется
        ContentList = new TableOfContentsViewModel()
        {
            new TableOfContentsItem() { ThemeID = 1, ThemeName = "Тема 1"},
            new TableOfContentsItem() { ThemeID = 2, ThemeName = "Тема 2"},
            new TableOfContentsItem() { ThemeID = 3, ThemeName = "Тема 3"},
            new TableOfContentsItem() { ThemeID = 4, ThemeName = "Тема 4"},
            new TableOfContentsItem() { ThemeID = 5, ThemeName = "Тема 5"},
            new TableOfContentsItem() { ThemeID = 6, ThemeName = "Тема 6"},
            new TableOfContentsItem() { ThemeID = 7, ThemeName = "Тема 7"}
        };

        // и вообще лучше это делать асинхронно, чтобы не морозить интерфейс, пока идет загрузка
        //_ = LoadTableOfContentsAsync();
    }
}

// вы не показали класс элемента списка, поэтому я придумал свой
public class TableOfContentsItem
{
    public int ThemeID { get; set; }
    public string ThemeName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => ThemeID + " " + ThemeName;
}

// чтобы не плодить сущности, я просто унаследовался от коллекции для VM списка
public class TableOfContentsViewModel : ObservableCollection<TableOfContentsItem>
{
    private ICommand _deleteItemCommand;
    private ICommand _editItemCommand;
    private ICommand _openItemCommand;

    // эта команда реализована и работает, остальные команды приведены как демо   
    public ICommand DeleteItemCommand => _deleteItemCommand ?? (_deleteItemCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        if (parameter is TableOfContentsItem item)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show(item.ToString(), "Удалить?", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question, MessageBoxResult.No) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }));

    public ICommand EditItemCommand => _editItemCommand ?? (_editItemCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        if (parameter is TableOfContentsItem item)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.ToString(), "Редактирование");
        }
    }));

    public ICommand OpenItemCommand => _openItemCommand ?? (_openItemCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        if (parameter is TableOfContentsItem item)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.ToString(), "Открытие");
        }
    }));
}
```

Этот ListView поддерживает динамическую ширину, то есть вы можете изменять размер окна и ширина списка будет меняться.

- добавлен триггер на видимость кнопок только при наведении мыши
- туда же воткнул проверку прав доступа через биндинг еще одним триггером на видимость
- добавлены `InputBindings` с примерами для мыши и клавиатуры
- это теперь не таблица
- стиль кнопки вынесен отдельно для демонстрации использования общих стилей

```xaml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ContentList}" 
        Margin="100,10"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"                              
        BorderThickness="0">
    <ListView.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Return"
                Command="{Binding ItemsSource.OpenItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
    </ListView.InputBindings>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="TableOfContentsButtonStyle">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="40"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsAdmin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TableOfContentsItem}">
            <Grid>
                <DockPanel>
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.InputBindings>
                            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick"
                                        Command="{Binding ItemsSource.OpenItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </Grid.InputBindings>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ThemeID}"
                                Width="50" Height="40"
                                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                Foreground="Black" FontSize="30"
                                TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ThemeName}"  
                                TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Foreground="Black" FontSize="20"/>
                        <Button Grid.Column="2"
                            Style="{StaticResource TableOfContentsButtonStyle}"
                            Content=""
                            ToolTip="Редактировать"
                            Command="{Binding ItemsSource.EditItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        <Button Grid.Column="3" 
                            Style="{StaticResource TableOfContentsButtonStyle}"
                            Content="❌" 
                            ToolTip="Удалить"
                            Command="{Binding ItemsSource.DeleteItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DockPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="60"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Это мне лет 5-10 изучать C# - то что вы тут понаписали =)

Comment: @jobsdata я дал краткий ответ под вашим вопросом

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ошибку
Если в XAML кнопки написать

```
Command="{Binding ElementName=TableOfContents, Path=DataContext.DeleteTheme}"
```

то всё работает