# Как получить текст с TextBlock который находится в ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как по нажатии картинки записать в переменную текст из TextBlock x:Name="tbIdBook"?

```
  <ListView  x:Name="listBook" 
                           BorderThickness="0" 
                           FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
                           Background="Transparent" 
                           d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData ItemCount=5}">

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid>

                                   <TextBlock x:Name="tbIdBook" Margin="110 0 0 0" 
                                              VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                              Panel.ZIndex="1" Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                          <Border 
                                                Canvas.Top="30"
                                                Width="100"                                                
                                                Margin="0 5 0 5"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"       
                                                BorderBrush="Blue"
                                                BorderThickness="1"
                                                CornerRadius="10">

                                                <Border.Effect>
                                                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20"
                                                        Opacity=".5"
                                                        ShadowDepth="1" />
                                                </Border.Effect>

                                                <Border Name="ReceiverColor"
                                                        BorderBrush="#FF96B2E4"
                                                        BorderThickness="2"                                                
                                                        CornerRadius="10">
                                                    <Grid>
                                                        <Border Name="Mask"
                                                               Background="White"
                                                               BorderBrush="#FF3B5998"
                                                               BorderThickness="0"
                                                               CornerRadius="10">
                                                        </Border>
                                                        <StackPanel>
                                                            <Image Stretch="Fill" MouseLeftButtonDown="imageBook_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                                                                   x:Name="imageBook"  Margin="5">
                                                                <Image.Source>
                                                                    <Binding Path="Image">
                                                                        <Binding.TargetNullValue>
                                                                            <ImageSource>
                                                                                /Resources/imageNull.png
                                                                            </ImageSource>

                                                                        </Binding.TargetNullValue>

                                                                    </Binding>
                                                                </Image.Source>
                                                            </Image>
                                                            <StackPanel.OpacityMask>
                                                                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Mask}" />
                                                            </StackPanel.OpacityMask>
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </Border>
                                          </Border>










private void imageBook_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
       var text = tbIdBook.Text   // не видет элемент             
    }
```

То есть, отсюда сюда обратится

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не вы должны ложить и забирать оттуда текст, а сам текстблок должен брать текст из ваших данных, отображать его и обновлять когда нужно. Это называется привязка данных (Data Binding). Эта технология нативно поддерживантся всеми контролами в WPF. Материалов по теме полно.

Comment: `Text="{Binding Id}"` что мешает взять этот `Id` там же, откуда он берётся в самом текстблоке? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1116136/373567