# Реализация DragDrop видеофайла при перемещении на ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, парсер, listview

Помогите реализовать методы для перетаскивания видеофайла из проводника на форму ListView.Информация о размещении видеофайла должна отображаться в GridView ,на выделенной строке ListView в кокретном cтолбце(поле) GridView.

```
private void ViewAllCards_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] handles = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
            foreach (string s in handles)
            {
                if (File.Exists(s))
                {
                    if (string.Compare(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(s), ".avi", true) == 0)
                    {
                        AddFileToViewAllCards(s);
                    }

                    if (string.Compare(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(s), ".mkv", true) == 0)
                    {
                        AddFileToViewAllCards(s);
                    }

                    if (string.Compare(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(s), ".mp4", true) == 0)
                    {
                        AddFileToViewAllCards(s);
                    }

                    if (string.Compare(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(s), ".wtv", true) == 0)
                    {
                        AddFileToViewAllCards(s);
                    }

                }
                
                else if (Directory.Exists(s))
                {
                    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(s);
                    FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.avi");
                    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
                    AddFileToViewAllCards(file.FullName);
                                        
                }
            }
        }

        
        public void AddFileToViewAllCards(string fullFilePath)
        {
            
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fullFilePath);
            string dirName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fullFilePath);
            if (dirName.EndsWith(Convert.ToString(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)))
            dirName = dirName.Substring(0, dirName.Length - 1);
            ViewAllCards.ItemsSource = null;

            ViewAllCards.Items.Clear();
            
            ViewAllCards.Items.Add(fileName);
            


        }
        private void ViewAllCards_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop, false) == true)
            {
                e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            }
            else 
                e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
```

Ничего не происходит, данные в ListView не отображаются

Comment: Что именно не получается? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5663329/12888024

Comment: `ViewAllCards.Items.Clear();` так вы при добавлении каждого очищаете список. И вообще познакомьтесь с привязками данных и ObservableCollection. А в `handles` что приходит?

Comment: Я пытаюсь закинуть на форму видео файл .avi из проводника

Comment: Не понятно как обозначить цель куда мой  файл должен распарситься(конкретное поле в List View)

Comment: `<ListView.ItemTemplate>` https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1116136/373567 или `GridView` с биндингами, я не знаю, что там у вас на самом деле.