# `MVVM` и `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm`

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, maui

Подскажите по `MVVM` и `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm`

Не могу сообразить как сделать так, чтобы `Model` уведомляла `ViewModel` об изменении свойств у `Model`.

Как я понял:

`ViewModel` нужно унаследовать от `ObservableRecipient`

`ViewModel` зарегистрировать для получения уведомлений и затем из `Model` отправлять уведомления.

Я сделал, это работает, но в данный момент отправляю просто копию `Model` из `Model` и обновляю свойства `ViewModel`.

**Model:**

```
Age++;
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new UserPropertyChangedMessage(this));
```

**ViewModel:**

```
Messenger.Register<UserViewModel, UserPropertyChangedMessage>(this, (r, m) => r.ReloadProperty(m));

public void ReloadProperty(UserPropertyChangedMessage message)
{
    Name = message.Value.Name;
    Age = message.Value.Age;
}
```

Но кажется,что как то сложно и неправильно

Можно как то проще подписаться `ViewModel` на изменение свойств `Model` ?

Comment: Про сообщения я писал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1470272/220553), ну а так... Вам не нужны они в данном случае, да и они больше VM фишка, чем M, вам достаточно сделать событие в модели, которое оповестит об изменении, а на него потом и подписывайтесь в VM, событие стандартное об изменении свойства - INPC, его вам делает [ObservableProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty), а дальше, в VM слое пишете `model.OnPropertyChanged += ...;`. Если нужно более логичное событие, то сделайте свое и по той-же логике.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - здорово! Спасибо!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а как совместить эти 2 артребута ? `[JsonIgnore]` `[ObservableProperty]` - игнорируется `[JsonIgnore]` и сериализуются свойства с ним(

Comment: Ни как?) Сериализация/Десериализация - это по сути, передача данных, а за это отвечают так называемые `DTO` классы, то есть классы, которые не должны иметь в себе логику, они **только** хранят в себе то, что должно быть передано. Ну а вы, как думаю уже поняли, нарушили это, и из передаваемых классов делаете функциональные, со своей логикой. Я даже уверен, что из тех данных, что вы получаете из JSON, вам половина не нужна, ну вот пусть в DTO будет все, а в отдельном классе пусть будет только нужное вам, а дальше перегоняйте данные из ... в ... (зовется маппинг)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ оО как сложно) не знал про DTO) - буду осваивать) У меня обычно класс делает сразу всё)))

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Вот эти все паттерны - это всё в книгах про архитектуры ? Я уже достаточно много читал книг просто по языку C# - по сути ток про лямбды / события и делегаты не усвоилось. Но про паттерны и структуры проектов в них ничего не было( Как вы черпаете эти знания ?

Comment: Без понятия) Каюсь, я не любитель книг. Весь мой опыт самоучки - это интернет и личные проекты, а не книги. Так что, не скажу что там в книгах и где.