# Как реализовать логирование в MVVM?

Tags: c#, mvvm, логирование

В проекте имеются модели: одна работает с файлами, другая с контроллером. В методах, существуют различные сообщения и обработка Exeption.
Так же в View существует TextBox, в котором хочу отображать сообщения, например:

```
[13/09/2023 12:00:00] Чтение конфигурации
[13/09/2023 12:05:05] Создание файла
[13/09/2023 12:05:45] Подключение к контроллеру
[13/09/2023 12:05:50] Подключено
[13/09/2023 12:10:00] [ERROR] Ошибка чтения тега в контроллере
[13/09/2023 12:10:00] Отключение от контроллера
```

Например:

Model работы с файлами:

```
public class Docs: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

   private string _path;
   private string _name;
   private string _result;

   public string Path 
   { 
      get => _path;
      set
      {
         _path = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Path");
      }
   }
   
   public string Name
   { 
      get => _name;
      set
      {
         _name= value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Name");
      }
   }

   public string Result
   { 
      get => _result;
      set
      {
         _result = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Result");
      }
   }

   public void CreateFile(object o)
   {
      using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(_path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
      {
       byte[] input = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(_name);
       fs.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
       Result = "Создание файла";
      }
   } 
}
```

Model работы с контроллером:

```
public class FX5U : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

   private bool _connected;
   private string _result;
   
   public bool Connected
   { 
      get => _connected;
      set
      {
         _connected= value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Connected");
      }
   }

   public string Result
   { 
      get => _result;
      set
      {
         _result = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Result");
      }
   }

   public void Connect(object o)
   {
     Result = "Подключение к контроллеру";
     PLC = new PLC();
     PLC.Connect();
     
     if (PLC.Connected)
     {
        Connected = true;
        Result = "Подключено"
     }
     else
     {
        Connected = false;
        Result = "Ошибка подключения";
     }
   } 
}
```

ViewModel:

```
internal class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  //....
  // инициализация
  //....

   public MainViewModel()
   {
      createFile = new DelegateCommand(docs.CreateFile);
      connectPlc = new DelegateCommand(plc.Connect, (o) => !plc.Connected);
   }
}
```

Как правильно реализовать логирование действий (Result) из разных моделей, в один TextBox?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если очень просто - создайте отдельную модель, которая будет отвечать за логирование, у нее методы отправки лога и другие, какие вам нужны, далее `event`, который будет оповещать всех подписчиков о том, что в лог что-то пришло, это событие в методах вызываете. Ну и дальше создаете **одну** модель и передаете ее во все классы через конструктор, где нужен лог. делая там что-то по типу `var logger = new Logger(); logger.NewLog += x => LogsHistory.Add(x);`, а где надо отправить делаете `logger.Log("Новый лог");`

Comment: Чтоб не возиться с постоянном внедрением зависимости, используйте DI контейнеры. Можно пойти иным путем, использовать генерацию кода и сообщения, об этом я писал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1470272/220553). Ну а если быть более умным, то советую использовать стандартные механизмы логгирования, а именно `ILogger`, который вы можете настроить как вам угодно, главное его правильно внедрить)