# WpfUI lepo.co Передать параметры в Page или его VM

Tags: c#, wpf

При использовании библиотеки [wpfui](https://github.com/lepoco/wpfui) столкнулся с проблемой передачи параметров на страницу. Использую готовый вариант навигации из данной библиотеки. Так же используется библиотека CommunityToolkit.Mvvm. Как именно можно передать определенный параметр при нажатии определенного элемента меню или выполнить команду ? [Проект шаблон](https://github.com/lepoco/wpfui/tree/development/src/Wpf.Ui.Extension.Template.Compact)

Comment: Вы не должны хотеть передавать что-то на страницу, вы должны оперировать данными, а если быть точней, то слоями VM. Вот у вас страница `A`, у нее есть `AViewModel`, аналогично страница `B` (`BViewModel`), вот вам надо передать что-то из `B` в `A`, вы в `BViewModel` передаете ссылку на `AViewModel` и вызываете там нужные публичные свойства или методы, готово. Так, как в данной библиотеке по умолчанию контейнер используется, то это все естественно делается через него. Ну и по хорошему, эту логику вынести в отдельный сервис.

Comment: Другой вариант. Так, как вы используете тулкит - использовать сообщения, это некие глобальные события на которые можно подписаться с любого места, вот в `AViewModel` подписываетесь на нужное событие, а в `BViewModel` отсылаете событие. Об этом я писал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1470272/220553)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо за ответ, в целом понятно, но я не очень понимаю тогда к какому событию подвязаться чтобы передавать значение. В чем вообще суть, элементы меню появляются постепенно (подгружаются из файла) и мне надо в 1 View (всегда 1 и тот же) разное значение передавать я думал уже через Properties как-то передать, но вопрос все еще в событии.

Comment: Сделайте отдельный класс, в котором будет коллекция, будет событие, будет метод добавления, удаления, и прочее. В методах дергайте событие. Сам класс регистрируйте в контейнере как отдельный сервис, его внедряйте в ваши VM, подписывайтесь на событие, вызывайте нужные методы, привязывайте.

Comment: Это то понятно, только вот мне бы определить к какому событию привязаться чтобы обновлять данные (событие при выборе элемента меню), а делать отдельный класс с листом и методами нет смысла т.к. уже есть тот же ObservableCollection там есть события и все такое.

Comment: "Нет смысла" - ошибаетесь, у вас есть одна конкретная логика, которая должна быть общей для несколько страниц. Ну вот допустим, реальный мир, машина, действия "ехать", "завести" это относится к конкретной машине, а "починить" уже относится к мастерской или даже к мастеру, который будет заниматься этой машиной, вот тоже самое и у вас. Не, дело ваше конечно, хотите городить все в одном месте, дерзайте, но яб вынес в отдельный сервис общую логику.

Comment: Что касается события - вам уже сказали в предыдущем вопросе, что у тулкита есть методы, которые вызываются при изменении свойства, сделайте свой `event` и дергайте это событие в этом методе, ну а где надо, подписывайтесь на это событие. Если экономите на спичках, то у вас должно быть событие `OnPropertyChanged` (или как-то так), подписывайтесь на него, а в обработчике делайте `if arg.Name == nameof(Класс.Свойство){ логика }`. Не бойтесь создавать свое, не ищите готовое!