# Как сделать в ListView список Title с крестиком напротив, чтобы по нажатию на крестик Title удалялся (wpf mvvm)?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listview

Если, через контекстное меню делаю или просто через кнопку работает, но как сделать так чтобы напротив текста был крестик который удалял бы этот самый item хз
xaml:

```xml
<Window x:Class="NotesTask.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NotesTask"
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:NotesTask.ViewModel"
        
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:NotesViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="28*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NotesModel.Notes}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedNote}" Margin="10,10,10,10">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Name="NoteTemplate">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"  MinHeight="25" MinWidth="100" Margin="3,3,3,3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Button Command="{Binding Path=RemoveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedNote}" Content="X" MinHeight="25" MinWidth="25" Margin="3,3,3,3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding Path=RemoveCommand}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListView.ContextMenu>
        </ListView>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" MinHeight="25" MinWidth="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Delete" Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

using NotesTask.Model;

namespace NotesTask.ViewModel
{
    internal class NotesViewModel
    {
        public Note InputedNote { get; set; }

        public Note SelectedNote { get; set; }

        public NoteModel NotesModel { get; set; } = new NoteModel();

        public ICommand AddCommand { get; set; }

        public ICommand RemoveCommand { get; set; }

        public NotesViewModel()
        {
            AddCommand = new RelayCommand(
                execute =>
                {
                    if (InputedNote != null)
                    {
                        NotesModel.Add(new Note(InputedNote.Title, InputedNote.Description));
                    }
                },

                canExecute =>
                {
                    if (InputedNote.Title != "")
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                );

            RemoveCommand = new RelayCommand(
                execute =>
                {
                    if (SelectedNote != null)
                    {
                        NotesModel.Remove(SelectedNote);
                    }
                },

                canExecute => SelectedNote != null
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1116136/373567

Comment: @aepot, Если все скопипастить то работает, но почему я не понимаю. Как так получается что кнопки ссылаются на removeCommand, если сам лист прибинден к коллекции в которой нет этой команды?

И что означает RelativeSource в данных командах: `Command="{Binding ItemsSource.DeleteItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"` ? Правильно понимаю что: RelativeSource= указывает к чему будет привязан объект, а AncestorType=ListView определяет предка кнопки,  {RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView} - вызывает сущность к которой привязан предок?

Comment: Обратите внимание на то как реализована коллекция, обычно в коллекцию не кладут команды, они где-то в обычных вьюмоделях живут или же в элементах коллекции. `public class TableOfContentsViewModel : ObservableCollection<TableOfContentsItem>` - конечно же так делать не обязательно. Про Ancestor вы верно поняли, что он ищет предка подходящего типа. Можно так к окну обращаться и к главной вьюмодели через `DataContext`.