# Получить "данные" при нажатии Кнопки?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

дорогие друзья!
Тыкните пожалуйста мое лицо в ссаную тряпку, но никак не могу сообразить...

Есть таблица DataGrid:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу при нажатии на Кнопку **Ping** в колонке Operations, получить значение из колонки IP Adress текущий строки... для дальнейших манипуляций.

Datagrid заполняю обычным кодом

```
ObservableCollection<User> users = new ObservableCollection<User>();

users.Add(new User { ... );
```

В Xaml у меня просто:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

    <DataTemplate>

        <Button Content="Ping" Click="Button_Click"/>

    </DataTemplate>

</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Обработчик кнопки (пусто):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    \\ я так понимаю тут я должен как-то отловить нужную строку...хз как..и получить
    \\ данные из ячейки строки, которая была выбрана..
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать!!!
Без всяких MVVM (для меня это пока дремучий лес!)

Comment: Это делается не через обработчик клика, через него это просто не сделать нормально, а через команду, и MVVM здесь не при чём.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь всё просто сделать через команду. MVVM здесь не требуется, это не про MVVM, это про команды.

Берём класс, упрощающий взаимодействие с командами и добавляем в проект, например в файл **RelayCommand.cs**.

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);
}
```

Назначаем `DataContext` окну прямо на него самого.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

`DataContext` нужен для работы привязок `Binding` в XAML. (в MVVM он назначается на экземпляр класса вью-модели)

Теперь вместо обработчика создаём саму команду

```
public ICommand PingCommand { get; } = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    User user = (User)parameter;
    // код
}, parameter => parameter is User); // это CanExecute если условие не выполняется, кнопка задизаблится
```

Кнопка проверяет `CanExecute` команды каждый раз перед выполнением команды примерно так:

```
if (command.CanExecute(parameter))
{
    command.Execute(parameter);
}
```

То есть это даёт гарантию, что вы никогда не получите `InvalidCastException` в строчке `(User)parameter`. Ну и плюс кнопка сама задизаблится, это удобно.

Если у вас команда такая, что `CanExecute` всегда `true`, то его можно просто не указывать, он необязателен.

И просто прописываем команду в кнопку

```xml
<Button Content="Ping"
        Command="{Binding PingCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource, AncestorType=Window}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

Готово. Никаких `x:Name` не требуется.

Answer (score 0):

Если без MVVM, то присваиваем DataGrid имя: `<DataGrid Name="dg" ... >`
и теперь в `Button_Click` можем получить нужную строку:

```
var selectedUser = dg.SelectedItem as User;
```

Ну а дальше из свойства получаете IP-адрес

Comment: Во блин, как все просто. Спасибо!!! Осталось понять/почитать про выражение после =...

Comment: @jobsdata выбранная строка и строка, в которой нажата кнопка, могут отличаться, это не решение.

Comment: @aepot можете по подробней?

Comment: @jobsdata https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1116136/373567 кстати, если вам данные не надо редактировать прямо в ячейках, DataGrid - лишнее, вам больше подойдёт ListView. Но это дело вкуса.